# UIView animations hang up in iphone for testing

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

My application was working with no problem in iphone simulator, but when I run it on iphone 4 (ios 5.1) some views' animations are not fluent and they sometimes falter. I use the code below, what might the problem be here?

```
- (void)moveAnimatedToPoint:(CGPoint)point after:(float)delay during:(CGFloat)duration willRemove:(BOOL)remove
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:delay
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y,
                                                 CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.frame));
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             if (remove)
                                 [self removeFromSuperview];
                             else {
                                 isHided = CGRectContainsRect(self.superview.frame, self.frame) ? NO : YES;
                             }
                         }
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is explained at below link very well. My views have shadow layers and they slow the transition animations.

http://mobileoverlord.com/instruments-optimizing-core-animation/

Answer (score -1):

Welcome in the real world outside of simulators :).

Depending on your animations (size, memory requirement etc.), your devices memory, your devices active tasks etc. this simply can happen ;).

Comment: hi, there is no active task background.

Comment: There are always active tasks. The devices operating system is doing things that you can not see. Updating time, handling interrupts etc.

Comment: No solution, live with it ;). The only thing you can do is make a smaller animation and hope that it runs smother or perhaps use OpenGL.

Comment: ok, thanks, but no help to me with these comments...

Comment: Nobody can help you with just looking at your code. Without knowing what kind of animation you are doing: size, frames, memory usage etc. and what other things your app is doing this is an impossible task. But I have to say it again: You can not animate a view in such way and be 100% sure that it runs smooth all the time!

Comment: i saw sample animations on another application in iPhone. so it can be done. also just some view transition from one point to another point, not a big task for memory.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing and what other apps are doing. Animating 5 frames with 10x50px images should be no problem. Animating 100 frames with 2024x1024px images should be impossible. Anything between... it depends. UIView animations are not very optimized. What you can do is change your animation or swap to OpenGL or tell us in detail what you are trying to animate

Comment: i explained only one view moves from one point to another point, this is at all, not complex task. but it hangs up at this moving.